# RDP Client - AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException

Tags: c#, winforms, activex, rdp

I working on application that will optimize my job, with multiple connection by means RDP to my  servers. At that point I will like to do a single windows form that show me all my servers. With my appropriate knowledge - I will like to add programmatically `AxMsRdpClient2` or `AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting` control in my windows form. At start I have a Form1 where I save my credential (IP,USER,PASS) and with simple `FOR`  I trung to add ActiveX Client to my Form2 and connect to the servers.

And here I have the problem. Lets see my code below.

call from Form1() >

```
var btt = new RunRDP();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        btt.PozitionMaster();
    }
```

RunRDP Class:

```
private static int _count;
private static int _row = 4;
private static int _colum = 4;
private static int _objId;

public void PozitionMaster()
    {
        if (_count != 6)
        {
            UInitializer(_objId++, _row, _colum);
            _row += 196;
            _count++;

        }
        else
        {
            _colum += 196;
            _row = 4;
            _count = 0;
        }
    }
```

UInitializer function:

```
public AxMsRdpClient2 rdpClient;

        public void UInitializer(int id, int x, int y)
        {
            Form2 ippo = new Form2();
            rdpClient = new AxMsRdpClient2();

            rdpClient.UserName = "username";
            rdpClient.Server = "192.168.0.100";
            rdpClient.Height = y;
            rdpClient.Width = x;

            rdpClient.BeginInit();
            rdpClient.CreateControl();


            if (ippo.InvokeRequired)
            {
                ippo.Invoke(new Action(() => ippo.Controls.Add(rdpClient)));
                ippo.Invoke(new Action(() => ippo.Update()));
            }
            else
            {
                ippo.Controls.Add(rdpClient);
            }

            //this.Controls.Add(rdpClient);

            rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RDPPort = 3389;
            rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = "hello_rdp";//     
            rdpClient.ColorDepth = 16;//     
            rdpClient.FullScreen = false;//     

            rdpClient.Connect();    
        }
```

get that error:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.
InvalidActiveXStateException' occurred in AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll

{"Exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown."}
```

Answer (score 4):

InvalidActiveXStateException is raised when you start using the ActiveX control *before* its native window is created.  That does not happen until *after* you call `ippo.Show();`  Move critical property assignments and method calls after that statement.

Comment: Thanks! It was the solution for me!